# Powershell: Nested Property, The property cannot be found on this object

Tags: powershell

I have nested JSON file that looks like this

```
{name:{firstname: Joe, lastname: Bloggs}}
```

I convert from Json and save as a variable

```
$json = Get-Content -Path .\file.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I have a function that retrieves the property path and saves it to a variable

```
$firstname = "name.firstname"
```

Why does

```
$json.$firstname
```

not return Joe? How can I get Powershell to understand that it should be interpreted as

```
$json.name.firstname
```

instead of

```
$json."name.firstname"
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"name.firstname"` is just a literal string, PowerShell doesn't know you are referring to the nested property `firstname` within the `name` property. You *could* expand the string via [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression?view=powershell-7.2#:%7E:text=%5B%5D-,Description,run%20in%20the%20current%20scope.) or [`$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.commandinvocationintrinsics.expandstring?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) though that's better to be avoid whenever possible. Here is another way to do it by traversing the path:

```
$json = '{name:{firstname: "Joe", lastname: "Bloggs"}}' | ConvertFrom-Json
$path = 'name.firstname'

$path.Split('.') | & {
    begin { $targetObject = $json }
    process { $targetObject = $targetObject.$_ }
    end { $targetObject }
}
```